# QML/Qt4 for desktop: any demos?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I want to build a simple desktop application using QML (need nice transition animations), but i can't find any demos. The demos on qt docs website are using some shared files i can't find (and anyway they have both pro and QML pro while my application has only one view, so it's really overkill). I've found some code on github, but it seems like it's Qt5 only.

What i'm building is simple QML app with JS logic (remote JSON API calls) and some C++ code for platform specific stuff. Mb QML is just wrong idea for me?

Thanks.

Comment: QML is good idea for you (to my mind). What shared files do you could not find? On the official web site for Qt 4.8 they are all available http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtquick.html#examples . QML pro files used for QmlViewer, you can use QDeclarativeView widget and load QML file on it. Some how-to on http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-integration.html

Comment: You just answered my question with this qt-4.8 links. The issue was the docs i've found was all about QtQuick2, so Qt5 specific.
P.S. Can you repost it as answer?

Comment: I'm glad to help you. My answer is so trivial.

Comment: There are so many sites with QT docs: trolltech (seems down however), nokia, qt. And this is confused me.

Comment: Why Qt 4, btw? If there's no real strong reason, I'd highly recommend latest Qt 5 and Qt Quick 2 and its Qt Quick Controls.

Comment: Because most linux distros are using qt4 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Qt 4.8.6** Qt Quick examples and demos located at [QML Examples and Demos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtquick.html#examples)

QML `.qmlproject` files used for QML Viewer but you can use `QDeclarativeView` widget and load QML file on it as described here: [Integrating QML Code with Existing Qt UI Code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-integration.html).

Comment: Also useful link for somebody new with QML: https://jryannel.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks for link! There are helpful examples! Why you use Qt 4 instead of Qt5?

Comment: Because i need linux support. And most distros are available with Qt4 only by default.